# How to replace string value with numeric then change string object to numeric?

Tags: python, pandas, string, replace, dtype

I have a dataset that has numeric values but in some cells it has <0.0001 which is string.  How can I replace these with 0.00005.  Then I can try to convert to float from string, it won't let me do it since this has to be replaced first.  Here is what I have tried and it hasn't worked.

dataframe 'new':

| ID | ALL |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | <0.0001 |
| 1 | <0.0001 |
| 1 | 15.2 |
| 1 | <0.0001 |
| 2 | 0.030 |
| 2 | <0.0001 |
| 3 | <0.0001 |

```
new.ALL[new.ALL == '<0.0001'] = '0.00005'
new.select_dtypes(exclude=np.number).replace(to_replace=['<0.0001'],value='0.00005')
```

neither one works and no error is thrown, it just won't replace it.

Comment: Use `df.loc[selector, column] = replacement` or `df[column].replace({k: v}, inplace=True)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work:

```
df['ALL'].str.replace('<0.0001','0.00005').astype('float')
0     0.00005
1     0.00005
2    15.20000
3     0.00005
4     0.03000
5     0.00005
6     0.00005
Name: ALL, dtype: float64
```

Comment: How do I get it to override the dataframe variable, not just print this out?

Comment: You can assign it: `df['ALL'] = df['ALL'].str.replace ...` or you can create a new column `df['ALL2'] = ...` Either should work.

Comment: @CelesteWilson, sorry, you just need to assign it back to the original column or save it as a new column with `df['new_column`] as @J4FFLE mentioned above.

Comment: @Karthik S, IT WORKED!!!!  THANK YOU SO MUCH!!!!!  Onward and upward!